# Definir valor default coluna SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Gostaria de saber como faço para definir um padrão de insert em uma coluna no SQL.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE XPTO(
       ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
       NOME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
       ATIVO CHAR(1) NOT NULL)
```

Neste caso, quero limitar o campo ATIVO para receber somente valores de 'S' ou 'N'.

Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode criar uma `constraint` para validar o domínio do campo:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[XPTO] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_ATIVO] CHECK (( [ATIVO]='S' OR [ATIVO]='N')) GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[XPTO] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_ATIVO] GO
```

Agora, para o seu caso específico, não é melhor usar um campo do tipo `bit`, que só vai aceitar 1 e 0 (S e N)?

Comment: é um caso de costume, não vejo como bom ou ruim. Existe algum boa prática para esses casos?

Comment: @LuizMartinez, nesse caso específico, é uma boa prática usar o tipo `bit`. Algumas razões de ser melhor: campo `bit` ocupa menos espaço. Além disso, o campo `char` pode te trazer dificuldades ao usar o `where`, caso o `COLLATE` do teu banco estiver diferenciando maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Comment: Entendi, aqui estamos usando o collate default do SQL (Latin1_General_CI_AS) acredito não haver problemas, em todo caso os campos já existiam, foi só uma questão de impedir a inserção de valores diferentes. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Luiz, você pode utilizar a restrição [CHECK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190377.aspx).

```
-- código #1
CREATE TABLE XPTO(
       ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
       NOME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
       ATIVO CHAR(1) NOT NULL check (ATIVO in ('S','N'))
);

-- código #2
CREATE TABLE XPTO(
       ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
       NOME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
       ATIVO CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
       constraint Ativo_SN check (ATIVO in ('S','N'))
);
```

Caso o banco de dados esteja definido com agrupamento (*collate*) que diferencie maiúsculas de minúsculas, deve-se então acrescentar o uso da função upper na comparação.

Comment: Não seria o mesmo que foi informado pelo Ricardo Pontual?

Comment: @LuizMartinez: Sim, o Ricardo também sugeriu o uso da restrição CHECK. A diferença é somente a forma: ele sugeriu através do comando ALTER TABLE e eu sugeri diretamente na definição da tabela. O resultado final é o mesmo. // Quando a tabela já existe, o método de realizar alterações nas tabelas é através do comando ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Entendi, foi o que suspeitava, como aqui os campos já existem, terei que utilizar o Alter Table, mas muito obrigado pela sugestão, vou guarda-la na manga para outra necessidade.